# Table of Content left aligns the first two rows on second page

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I'm trying to create a template with an Table of Contents in Microsoft Word. This template is used to generate some documentation. Because it's a big document, the ToC is too big to fit on one page. On the first page of the ToC, there is no problem with the alignment, but on the second page, the first two rows are too far left aligned. See image below

Current ToC

[image]

From what I can tell, the box surrounding the ToC on the second page is indented, but I can't figure out how to fix that.

If anyone have any suggestions, that would be great!

Comment: See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm. No one here is going to be able to give valid advice based on a screenshot. Actual document with problem needed.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!

Most probably it had to do with the header and the picture that was there. I increased the header by 0.8 and the indentation of the ToC was gone.